# reply to Ajax post request with nodejs backend

Tags: node.js, ajax, forms, post

i'm trying to make a form on my website using jquery and ajax.
in the backend i have express installed.
when i make a post request to /mail and everything is ok i want to send json back to the contact page. how can i do that?

i've built the front end and the backend but i can't figure out how to send a success status or something like that to the front end.

this is my server script:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/contact.html");
});
app.post("/mail", (req, res) => {
  //here i want to respond with success or error to the front end

});
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello");
});



app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on http://localhost:${port}`));
```

this is my front end script:

```
$(function() {

    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#contact-form');

    // Get the messages div.
    var formMessages = $('.form-messege');

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        e.preventDefault();

        // Serialize the form data.
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(formMessages).addClass('success');

            // Set the message text.
            $(formMessages).text(response);

            // Clear the form.
            $('#contact-form input,#contact-form textarea').val('');
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
            $(formMessages).addClass('error');

            // Set the message text.
            if (data.responseText !== '') {
                $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
            } else {
                $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

how can i init the fail or done function in the ajax request?

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: i dont get an error. it just stays on the /mail route and displays the result object.

Comment: try this 
app.post("/mail", (req, res) => {
  var data={
    name: "uday"
  }
  res.status(200).json(data)
});